# Finding Max/Min Consecutive XOR value

Tags: performance, algorithm, data-structures

I have following problem : given an integer array (maximum size 50000) i have to find the maximum X such that,

```
X = a[p] ^ a[p+1] ^ ... ... ^ a[q] for some p,q (p<=q)
```

Also i have to find the minimum value of X.

I have tried this process ,

```
sum[i] = a[0] ^ a[1] ^ ... ... ^ a[i] for some i .
```

i pre-calculated it in O(n) and

then the value of X for some `p,q(p<=q)` is ,

```
X = sum[q] ^ sum[p-1]

MaxAns = Max of X for every pair of p,q (p<=q)

MinAns = Min of X for every pair of p,q (p<=q)
```

But this process is O(n^2).

How can i do that without O(n^2) algorithm , something more efficient ?

Comment: Not that it really helps you but if I remember properly, there's a problem which looks like this one in "Programming Pearls".

I think this is it with addition instead of XOR (I don't know how much of it you can adapt), in Column 8 "Algorithm design techniques".

Comment: i'm sorry, what is "Programming perls"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This algorithm works only for unsigned integers with limited bit width.

1. **Calculate prefix sum** for each array element (exactly as this is done in OP).
2. **Add each prefix sum to a radix tree** (most significant bit corresponding to the root, least significant bit corresponding to leafs).
3. Between calculating `sum[q]` and adding it to the radix tree, **search** `sum[q]` in the partially built radix tree (to get a minimum value of X). For maximum value of X, search `~sum[q]`.
4. If any bit of `sum[q]` (or `~sum[q]`) is missing from the tree, **toggle** this bit in the min/max value of X and continue search down the tree.
5. **Get minimum/maximum** of all min/max values, found for each prefix.

Time complexity is O(N log M), where M is the maximum value of array's elements.

Comment: thanks a lot for your thoughtful answer. i don't know the radix tree data structure (my bad !) , can you give me some link from where i can learn the implementation of radix tree FOR SOLVING MY PROBLEM. thanks again.

Comment: @palatok: I think Wikipedia article contains pretty good explanation: [Radix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree). Or you can use a simpler (but less efficient) structure instead: [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Answer (score 1):

**This is plain wrong - not sure why but a bit of testing seems to show it's wrong.**

I think you can get some inspiration from the column 8 of "Programming Pearls" where the problem is basically : "Given the real vector x[n], compute the maximum sum found in any contiguous subvector".

I think you can reuse the different algorithms replacing additions and subtractions by exclusive-or (most of the interesting properties are kept during the process : 0 is still the neutral elements, exclusive-or is its own inverse, commutativity).

You can find the slides : http://cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/s08.pdf but I definitely recommend the book.

Comment: If this is the algorithm I think it is, it won't work even in simple cases like [1,3].

Comment: Arg, I'll try this later out of curiosity. Sorry for this.

Answer (score 0):

**Algorithm :**

Initialize:

```
ans=a[0]
cur=a[0]
```

Loop for each element of the array:

```
(a) cur = max(a[i], cur^a[i])
(b) ans = max(cur, ans)
return ans
```

Example : 
Let array be 1 2 3 5 8 10

```
ans=cur=1

for i=1:

cur = max(2,3) = 3

ans = max(1,3) = 3


for i=2:

cur = max(3,0) = 3

ans = max(3,3) = 3


for i=3:

cur = max(5,6) = 6

ans = max(6,3) = 6


for i=4:

cur = max(8,14) = 14

ans = max(6,14) = 14


for i=5:

cur = max(10,4) = 10

anx = max(14,10) = 14
```

So, ans = 14

**Here is my implentation in C++**

```
int maxXOR(int a[], int n)
{
    int ans = a[0],cur=a[0];
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        cur=std::max(a[i],cur^a[i]);
        ans=std::max(ans,cur);
    }
    return ans;
}
```

**Analysis :**

```
Time Complexity : O(n)
Space Complexity : O(1)
```

Comment: For this array : {6, 8, 2, 4, 2} your program gives 8 as output BUT right answer is 14. Sorry to say, you wrote the algorithm without completely understanding the problem.

Comment: It gives 14, I checked it again. But still if you wish, I can put my main() function also over here.

Comment: For the array {2,4,3} your code will give output as 6 but the correct answer is 7.